# best practice to define function inside the angular controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular 1.X we can define the scope function as below , wanted to know what is best practice to define the function in scope.
please help me understand if any of the below approach is preferred over the other!!

```
// first approach
angular.controller("MyController", function() {
  $scope.firstFun = function() {
    // do something here
  };
});

// second approach
var firstFun = function($scope) {
  return function() {
    //use scope here and declare logic also
  };
};
angular.controller("MyController", function() {
  $scope.firstFun = firstFun($scope);
});
```

Comment: You're missing the $scope parameter for the controller.

Comment: Answering "Best Practices" isn't really the goal of this site;  Generally, Best Practices type questions are Opinionated and can have more than one valid answer.  This site is more focused on solving **problems** in code.

Comment: That being said, There is a Style Guide for angular available, written by John Papa.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Accessing $scope at all inside of your controllers is an anti-pattern and should only be done as a last resort. I second the recommendation of John Papa's style guide, but will add that it is a bit dated. If you're writing new code in Angular 1.5.x you should be using components as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there's a better approach than the two you listed, it's something like this:

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("YourModule")
        .controller("MyController", MyController);

    function MyController() {
        var ctrl = this;
        // All controller functions and variables bindings 
        // will be listed below, in alphabetic order
        ctrl.firstFun = firstFun;
        ctrl.myName = "name";

        function firstFun() {
        }
    }
}(angular));
```

I don't think that a short code is a well written one. So if I were you, I would give [John Papa's Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) a try.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer 1st approach of declaring a function. There is no additional benefit of using one approach over the other. Infact in 2nd approach, you would have to write few extra lines of code. You can follow any approach which you find more convenient to use.

Comment: With the second approarch, teh developer can reuse the function in multiple controllers. Ok, this is not the best pattern to do this (this is not the Angular way, that tells to write services for this), but this is a benefit.